# How to repeat the data from array Start data up to End data and again Start data in IOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to repeat the data while loading from array `Start data` up to `End data` and again `Start data` in IOS objective c. I have implemented the following code. I have use  `@try {  } @catch` to Handel the exception and stop to crash from `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array error` but I want to implement some better way

```
@interface CategoryVC ()
{
    NSArray* GradientColour;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     /*Gradient Colours*/
    GradientColour = @[CategoryEntertainmen2,CategoryGroceries2,CategoryAutomobile, CategoryClothing
                        , CategoryComputer,Categoryeducation,CategoryElectronics,CategoryEntertainment,CategoryGroceries,CategoryHealthButy,CategoryHome,CategoryResturant,CategoryToys,CategoryEntertainmen2,
        CategoryGroceries2,CategoryHealthButy2,CategoryHome2,CategoryResturant2,CategoryToys2,CategoryFlowers,CategoryBreakfast,
        CategorySpicyFood,CategoryFuriture 
                       ];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      /*Gradient Colours*/
    if (indexPath.row <23)
    {
      [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grass"] andColor:[ GradientColour  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }else{
        @try {
            [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grass"] andColor:[ GradientColour  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-23]];
        } @catch (id theException) {
            /*Handell Crash Conditions*/
            [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grass"] andColor:[ GradientColour  objectAtIndex:5]];
        }

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your intentions correctly, there is a specific operation for what you want, and it's called [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). You can do it with a single line of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Set up cell
    NSUInteger index = indexPath.row % GradidentColour.count;
    [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Grass"] andColor:[GradientColour  objectAtIndex:index]];
    return cell;
}
```

The `%` operator finds the reminder from division of `indexPath.row` by 23.

Comment: You can tweak it further by replacing hardcoded 23 with the count of datasource array.

Comment: I want to repeat the data while loading from array Start data up to End data and again Start data up to End data  repeatedly Start data up to End data

Comment: I know what i m doing is not good method so I am searching for the answer. Any way did you understand my questions

Comment: @nischalhada This code does exactly that. You could try this snippet and don't forget to set a high number of rows.

Comment: @nischalhada I gave the answer to your question as I understood it. Try this code, if it does not solve your problem, then please clarify your question.

Comment: ok i will try your code and reply you  Any way can you explain me how does reminder help us to repeat some fixed data I am interested to learn your logic so that